# A single CSV column includes commas - Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file, with 3 columns. But, one of these 3 columns include commas that break the CSV format.  My csv is as below:

```
id,name,score
1,Black,1
2, Brown,J,0
```

I want to copy only the second column in a different CSV file. My code looks like below:

```
for row in inpTweets:
            total_score = 0
            name = row [1]
writer.writerow([row [1], total_score])
```

Is there any appropriate way to change this format, in order to choose all the name field using python?

Comment: Are you *producing* this CSV file, or are you trying to *read* this broken CSV file? If just reading: well, it's *broken* and it's ambiguous where the value ends and where the column ends. For some very limited usecase it may be possible to have enough information to fix it, but we can't be sure without a lot more information on the issue.

Comment: i am reading it. So what kind on info must be added?

Comment: There is no general fix for broken CSV formats. To come up with a specific fix for your specific data we need to know what your data looks like exactly. Is the above sample representative? Could that be expressed as *integer, followed by some string, ending with integer*? Is it guaranteed that no additional commas are in any other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your source CSV file is malformed, you will get a different number of elements when the CSV reader splits the various lines. For example,

```python
import csv
with open(r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\broken.csv', 'rb') as csv_in:
    inpTweets = csv.reader(csv_in, skipinitialspace=True)
    header_row = True
    for row in inpTweets:
        if header_row:
            header_row = False
        else:
            print(row)
```

will print

```
['1', 'Black', '1']
['2', 'Brown', 'J', '0']
```

Notice that the first list conains three (3) elements and the second list contains four (4) elements.

If we *know* that

- the source file is supposed to contain only three columns, and
- the first and last columns are "id" and "score"

then we can "glue" second column back together from the intermediate elements in the list, i.e.,

```python
row[1] + ', ' + row[2] + ... + row[n-1]
```

That can be done with a *list comprehension* over `range(1, len(row) - 1)` ...

```python
[row[x] for x in range(1, len(row) - 1)]
```

... which we can then pass to `', '.join()` to "glue" the individual elements back into a string

```python
', '.join([row[x] for x in range(1, len(row) - 1)])
```

The final code would look something like this:

```python
import csv
with open(r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\broken.csv', 'rb') as csv_in:
    inpTweets = csv.reader(csv_in, skipinitialspace=True)
    with open(r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\output.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_out, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        header_row = True
        for row in inpTweets:
            if header_row:
                header_row = False
            else:
                out_row = [', '.join([row[x] for x in range(1, len(row) - 1)]), 0]
                writer.writerow(out_row)
```

and the resulting output CSV file would be

```
"Black",0
"Brown, J",0
```